# How to solve an error with imgproc.hpp and core.hpp?

Tags: c++, opencv

i used a c++ programm for image processing using opencv 2.1. and that program has below include files:

```
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
```

but after debuging the program i get error message as:

**fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'opencv2/core/core.hpp': No such file or directory.**

that is same as for **imgproc.hpp** and **highgui.hpp** after that i changed  `#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"` to `#include <highgui.h>` and that error solved.

But i could not find a solution for **imgproc.hpp** and **highgui.hpp** and there are no files named **imgproc.hpp** and **highgui.hpp** inside the opencv folder.

How can i solve this error?

Comment: If there are no files in the opencv folder, how you wanna include them?

Comment: actually i think there may be have a method to solve this. because when i changed `#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"` as `#include <highgui.h>` one error was solved

Comment: what IDE you're using, if any? Did you give the pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv arguments?

Comment: For me, `#include <opencv/highgui.h>` works fine, but I've only used OpenCV 2.3 and 2.4. I have never found the need to include the `.hpp` files (despite seeing it in some of the examples).

Answer (score 1):

From the path separator, I assume you are using *nix OS. So the following shell commands should help you to find the correct location of the header files:

```
locate highgui.h
locate highgui.hpp
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped me figure out where opencv2 were installed.

Answer (score -3):

As previously stated, your libraries aren't in an included area. Most people have tailored their responses to a Linux-based system, but if you're on Windows (i.e. Using Visual Studio), you can usually just include the entire path of your library folder in the include statement.

For example:

```
#include "C:\OpenCV\bin\install\opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp"
#include "C:\OpenCV\bin\install\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp"
```

I recently had my fair share of errors after trying to install OpenCV 2.4.1 and finding the correct directories to include (both for 'include' and 'lib') was difficult at first. I recommend re-installing your OpenCV and going from there.

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/InstallGuide